# Convert project to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-c++

How can I convert my application from Visual Studio 6.0 to Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 2):

I think that conversion is builtin. There is a [conversion wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60z6y467.aspx) that helps you, so just try opening your solution in the latest studio version you have.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that converting to a VS2008 project is a destructive process -- VS does not automatically backup your VC6 project. You will be better served to create a copy and work on that, so that even in case something goes wrong you have a way to revert back.

Answer (score 0):

Probably buildin in VS. Recently i converted a project from VS6 to VS2005. So to 2008 won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened a client's VS 6.0 C++ application in VS2008 a couple of days ago. The conversion was completely automated (via a wizard). Totally painless (although this was a simple test application).

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from VS6 to VS2008? I think you're probably converting a VB app, or are you?

The Conversion Wizard (File->Open) will automatically convert the older project types to new ones. Remember to keep a backup when you use it.